# Renaming of Computer Name

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to get details of when and by whom the computer name was renamed.

I found that if a  renaming  is done for a computer an event id *6011* will be generated in event logs.

I am trying to pull the details of who did the rename using below command

```
Get-EventLog -LogName System | where {$_.EventID -eq 6011}
```

But its not giving the required result.

Comment: Could it be that the System event log has rolled over since the last time the machine was renamed?

Comment: That info might also be in `C:\windows\debug\netsetup.log` as that I don't think gets rolled over. (If that machine is domain joined)

Comment: @BenH i have checked that log. It shows the time of the rename , but it doesnt provide data regarding who changed it.
Please help me to get the data of who changed the server name

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen. I am getting data from that such as old host name and new hostnames. But event id doesnt provide data regarding who changed it. Pls help me to get that

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, but you can check the EventLog if you have logs with ID (6012).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31001374)